# Backing up my data on Cumulocity Edge/Cloud

Tags: backup, restore, cumulocity

How can I backup/restore the data on Cumulocity? 
Is there any backup feature or service on this platform?

This feature is specially needed when we use the **Edge solution** and something goes wrong with the edge server i.e. the Hard Disk defects.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you are hosting the Cumulocity Edge VM you can export snapshots, e.g. on Hyper-V machines. This snapshot could then be archived/stored anywhere else.